# Java split a string into multiple ones at a selected position

Tags: java, string, printing, graphics2d, drawstring

I'm trying to make a method which will split a long text into lines and draw them on documents using Graphics. I managed to figure out how to split the lines that I get from a JTextArea component but don't know how to make them wrap/break when a line gets too long.

Here's my code so far:

```
    void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y, Font w) {
        g.setFont(w);
        for (String line : text.split("\n"))
            g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

My thoughts on a fix about this is to calculate the char position of the string and if it reaches a selected position then I add a line break `("\n")` there. Any other suggestions or should I go for this one?

Comment: What do you mean ? The current code works well with new lines but not when they get too long.

Comment: I was misreading, I will delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word count method like this instead of the split method:

```
public String[] splitIntoLine(String input, int maxCharInLine){

StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
int lineLen = 0;
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String word = tok.nextToken();

    while(word.length() > maxCharInLine){
        output.append(word.substring(0, maxCharInLine-lineLen) + "\n");
        word = word.substring(maxCharInLine-lineLen);
        lineLen = 0;
    }

    if (lineLen + word.length() > maxCharInLine) {
        output.append("\n");
        lineLen = 0;
    }
    output.append(word).append(" ");

    lineLen += word.length() + 1;
}
// output.split();
// return output.toString();
return output.toString().split("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap `code` section in quote section, unless it is really quotation in which case you should also include its source in your answer.

Comment: Also `.append(word + " ")` is sign that someone doesn't understand purpose of StringBuilder. It is used to avoid string concatenation which creates its own new StringBuilder which means that this code is same as `.append(new StringBuilder(word).append(" ").toString())`. We should use `append(word).append(" ")` instead.